# Bootstrap 3 make not swipe body page on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have bug on Iphone, when I can drag the whole layout side to side so I can see the wight "background" and when I let it go it's springs back into place.
But I use not wight background.

I used bootstrap 3.
And add

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
```

I not have 10 reputation, for add picture.

Add dropbox link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gydhi17tj77swcq/IMG_1316.PNG?dl=0